# Plot a dataframe with different values and categories on quarterly basis in r as a histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I have a problem with my dataset and I would like to create a histogram showing the distribution of observations per quarter. The observations are divided into 3 categories and should be displayed per quarter.
Unfortunately, I have not yet found out how it works. With a "normal" plot I have added the respective observation points via the command "points", but I don't quite know how this works with histograms. Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is a sample of my data (in real there are about 20 years of observations with its categories):

```
            date    n           Categorie1 Categorie2 Categorie3
         2015 Q1    67                5          2          1
         2015 Q2    71                3          4          2
         2015 Q3    69                2         10         11
         2015 Q4    62                1          0          0 
         2016 Q1    69                2          2          1
         2016 Q2    61                3          5          0
         2016 Q3    63                3          2          7
```

The variable "date" is in the format 'yearqtr'.

I have used the following code to produce the normal plot:

```
> plot(df23$date,df23$Categorie1 , col = "red", pch = 16, xlab="Quarter",
> ylab="Occurencies")
>     points(df23$date,df23$Categorie2 , col = "blue", pch = 16)
>     points(df23$date,df23$Categorie3 , col = "green", pch = 16)
```

So I get a graph, but I don't know how to get this histogram for the different categories per quarter.

Can you please help me to create the histogram for the different categories and the different quarters?

Many thanks in advance!

This is my dput(df23):

```
>  dput(df23)
structure(list(date = structure(c(2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 
2016, 2016.25, 2016.5), class = "yearqtr"), n = c(67, 71, 69, 
62, 69, 61, 63), Categorie1 = c(5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3), Categorie2 = c(2, 
4, 10, 0, 2, 5, 2), Categorie3 = c(1, 2, 11, 0, 1, 0, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please paste your data into the question using `dput(df23)` to make it easily reproducible? [Guidance for making a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) Do you need a base R graphics solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Gal's approach is very good. Here is an alternative way:

1. Bring you data in long format with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` package is in `tidyverse`
2. As your date column is already fine, you could use it `as.factor` without `date` format (otherwise see Martin Gal's solution)
3. You could also use `geom_col`

```
library(tidyverse)

df23 %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -c(date, n),
        names_to = "Categorie"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = factor(date), y = value, fill = Categorie)) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: When factoring, take care for the correct order of the dates. +1

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked very well! 
Is it possible to rename the axes in this histogram? So e.g. call the x-axis "Quarter" and the y-axis "Occurencies"?

Comment: Add `+ xlab("Quarter") + ylab("Occurencies")`

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know how to adjust the colors of the histogram? So you can choose the colors for the different categories?

Comment: add this line to the code `scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))`

Answer (score 3):

Using a `tidyverse` approach we could do

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo) # format "yearqtr"


df23 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("Categorie"), 
    names_to = "Categorie",
    names_pattern = "Categorie(\\d+)"
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, fill = Categorie)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

to get

[image]

### Data

```r
df23 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(2015, 2015.25, 2015.5, 2015.75, 
2016, 2016.25, 2016.5), class = "yearqtr"), n = c(67, 71, 69, 
62, 69, 61, 63), Categorie1 = c(5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3), Categorie2 = c(2, 
4, 10, 0, 2, 5, 2), Categorie3 = c(1, 2, 11, 0, 1, 0, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you adjust the code, if the categories have different names? So for example categorie 1 is named "daimler", categorie 2 is named "opel" and categorie 3 is named "renault"?

Comment: If your categories are named differently, replace the ´pivot_longer` statement by `pivot_longer(-c(date,n), names_to = "Categorie")`.